# Cropped picture in TV when connecting laptop to TV with HDMI

Tags: laptop, resolution, hdmi, tv, crop

I have this TV http://www.hdtvsolutions.com/pdf/LC370SL8.pdf and an HP Pavilion dv6 laptop.

When connecting the latop to the TV with HDMI I set the resolution 1280x720 on the TV (it's strange, according to http://www.hdtvsolutions.com/pdf/LC370SL8.pdf the TV supports WXGA 1366x768, but when I set that resolution, TV's picture shakes. So, with 1280x720 the TV works fine).

But TV's picture is cropped from each side by around 60px; I don't see all the sides normally. Why does it happen?

What I can only do is to customize the aspect ratio. Changing the resolution/other settings doesn't help.